# How often does a user type in the "last 4 digits of SSN" in the "last 4 digits of Phone"?

Tags: phishing, information-gathering, password-reset

This may sound dumb to a Security pro, but this is about end-users and worst case interaction with a challenge-response.

**Background**

Many 2 factor authentication sites request verification of the last 4 digits of a phone number.  This is unique in the US, because our phone number format is (xxx) xxx - xxxx.  (other countries may not have this culture format)

I have witnessed a number of login failures from legitimate users and suspect they are using another common 4 digit code instead of their phone number.

I have no desire to inadvertently collect SSNs in my logfile, and it's possible malicious actors could try to collect this information by using a similar scheme (in the guise of resetting a password).

**Question**

Does empirical evidence exist to suggest that a user population may enter SSNs in the phone number entry field?

Comment: This is probably a better question for http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I often catch myself tipping my PIN on those mobile debit machines at restaurants